# python class functions error

Tags: python, oop

I am a python newbie and I’m trying to write simple project using OOP way.

The first function waits for user interface to enter the user first name.

The second function waits for user interface to enter the user last name.

THEN

The third function prints the full name.

But

When I tried to initiate these functions, it gives me errors.

Here is the code:

```
class UserFullName:
    def __init__(self, FirstName, LastName, FullName):
        self.FirstName = FirstName
        self.LastName = LastName
        self.FullName = FullName


    def FirstName(self):
        FirstName = input("enter your first name:\n".title())
        return FirstName

    def LastName(self):
        LastName = input("enter your last name:\n".title())
        return LastName

    def FullName(self, FirstName, LastName):
        print('welcome', "{} {}".format(FirstName, LastName).title())
        return

UserFullName.FirstName()
UserFullName.LastName()
UserFullName.FullName()
```

Here is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "E:/Tutorial/pan.py", line 20, in

```
UserFullName.FirstName()
```

TypeError: FirstName() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: You have to create an object of class `UserFullName` first (`name = UserFullName(...)`). You might want to do some more reading on the basics of OOP.

Comment: So, your __init__ will be executed every time that you try to initialize your class.

Comment: All of the answers down there fix one or two of your mistakes, but if you want to write actually good and useful and correct code, you have to read a tutorial about classes. A StackOverflow answer can't replace a tutorial.

Comment: @Aran-Fey one or two of my mistakes !!! wow can you please tell me how really really bad is it? for learning purpose

Comment: Well, basically everything except the constructor (the `__init__`) is wrong or useless or poorly designed. Methods that never use the `self` variable shouldn't be defined in a class. You also never created an instance of your class, making it doubly useless. And there are very few scenarios in which a class should take user input.

Comment: I found four serious mistakes from a quick glance. I tried to guess which one you were actually stuck on and fix just that one, then I rewrote things to address all four—but really, Arab-Fay is right, you need to work through a tutorial.

Comment: @abarnert Nice typo :P

Comment: thanx guys for great help & support

Comment: @Aran-Fey My iPhone autocorrect insists that you really are an elf from Riyadh, and who am I to argue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example use the **init** function that will be executed all the time that you initialize the class, if you don't want use it you can use the follow example provide by other users

As advice for string I advice to use raw_input, anyway the following will work:

```
class UserFullName():
    def __init__(self):
        self.FirstName()
        self.LastName()
        self.FullName()

    def FirstName(self):
        self.FirstName = raw_input("enter your first name:\n")

    def LastName(self):
        self.LastName = raw_input("enter your last name:\n")

    def FullName(self):
        print("Welcome "+str(self.FirstName)+" "+str(self.LastName))

UserFullName()
```

if you want a return in the first 2 methods you can do even in this other way:

```
class UserFullName():
    def __init__(self):
        name=self.FirstName()
        surname=self.LastName()
        self.FullName(name,surname)

    def FirstName(self):
        FirstName = raw_input("enter your first name:\n")
        return (FirstName)

    def LastName(self):
        LastName = raw_input("enter your last name:\n")
        return (LastName)

    def FullName(self, name, surname):
        print("Welcome "+str(name)+" "+str(surname))

UserFullName()
```

Comment: why -1? :S it's working and with 2 example to understand better how it works :S

Comment: Telling someone how to port his 3.x code to 2.x without even telling him that you’re doing that is hardly helpful advice.

Comment: ok I didn't explain that in python 3 raw_input was replaced with input but for the rest this code is working perfectly on python 3

Comment: Even if you did explain that, why would you advise a Python 3 user to switch his existing, working `input` calls to `raw_input` just so you can then explain that he should change that to `input` like he originally had?

Comment: yeah I was on rush, as tag I read only python and I wrote without think seeing that I use to use more python 2 than 3... but it's a very easy class, not so much to understand, anyway I'll keep on mind your advice and I'll try to answer better next time, even if I want just help the community seeing that some time I ask question too

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this the OOP way, you want to make your object's state—that is, the user's first and last names—be part of the object. Like this:

```
def FirstName(self):
    self.FirstName = input("enter your first name:\n".title())
    return self.FirstName

def LastName(self):
    self.LastName = input("enter your last name:\n".title())
    return self.LastName

def FullName(self, FirstName, LastName):
    print('welcome', "{} {}".format(self.FirstName, self.LastName).title())
    return
```

That `self.FirstName` is a member of the object, which can be accessed from other methods.

---

But you also have to *call* these methods on an object. Which means you have to create an instance of the class:

```
user = UserFullName()
user.FirstName()
user.LastName()
user.FullName()
```

---

Except that won't work as-is either, because of two other problems.

First, your methods have the same name as your attributes. Once you've set `self.FirstName`, you can never call the `FirstName` method again, because you've hidden it.

Second, your initializer requires you to pass in first, last, and full names. But you don't have those names yet! They only come later, when you call those methods with `input` in them. So you'd have to do something like `user = UserFullName('', '', '')`. But a better solution is to remove the `__init__` method entirely, or to rearrange things so the `input` happens before creating the class, and you can pass the names in, instead of doing it inside methods.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sure. I added an explanation of how to fix his next problem. But my goal isn't to debug everything and write all his code, it's to teach him how to solve his problem.

Comment: I think his problem is primarily about _object vs class_ first, with _object-associated variables_ second. But after your edit the solution is fine.

Comment: @abarnert I don't think an answer that only addresses one of the countless problems in the OP's code would've been very useful. A comment saying "You should read a tutorial about classes" would be more useful than that.

Comment: @Aran-Fey OK, I've rewritten it to explain all four of the big problems I saw, not just the one I think he's asking about, with explicit code for the first two and explanations of how to fix it himself for the next two. Does that seem like around the right balance? (And also, did I miss any more big mistakes in the code?)

Answer (score -1):

You called `UserFullName` but didn't insatiate it by giving it arguments provided in the `__init__` function. Try something like `UserFullName(FirstName='James', LastName='Sull', FullName='James Sull').FirstName()` instead.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to use class variable  , you need to use self to reference it and try to not using same name for variable and method.
btw you need to create instance of class to use

```
  class UserFullName:
        def FirstName(self):
            self.firstName = input("enter your first name:\n".title())
            return self.firstName

        def LastName(self):
            self.lastName = input("enter your last name:\n".title())
            return self.lastName

        def FullName(self):
            print('welcome', "{} {}".format(self.firstName, self.lastName).title())



    userFullName = UserFullName()
    userFullName.FirstName()
    userFullName.LastName()
    userFullName.FullName()

    Enter Your First Name:
    1
    Enter Your Last Name:
    2
    ('welcome', '1 2')
```

or if you prefer class method

```
class UserFullName:
        @classmethod
        def FirstName(self):
            self.firstName = input("enter your first name:\n".title())
            return self.firstName
        @classmethod
        def LastName(self):
            self.lastName = input("enter your last name:\n".title())
            return self.lastName
        @classmethod
        def FullName(self):
            print('welcome', "{} {}".format(self.firstName, self.lastName).title())

UserFullName.FirstName()
UserFullName.LastName()
UserFullName.FullName()

Enter Your First Name:
1
Enter Your Last Name:
2
('welcome', '1 2')
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey why not?

Comment: Again, the problem about _object vs class_ first (for functionality at least).